# How to display the more than one button in a single cell when using data tables?

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatables, codeigniter-3

I am displaying data from the database in the data tables and list are displaying.

Now I have to add the more than two buttons in the status column.

like

```
Name  | Mobile    | Email       | Status         
mnb   |1235412541 |nb@gmail.com | view | pending
```

So I tried two times return

First, return always display the view button and second return depending on the condition will return.
I am getting only view button.

Would you help me out how to display the more than one button in a single cell?

```
{ "data": null, 
"render": function (data, type, full, meta) { 
    return "<a href='"+baseUrl+"/Controller_control/get_customer?key="+full["cust_id"]+"'><img src='"+baseUrl+"/assets/images/icons/view.png'></a>"; 
    switch(full["o_order_status"]) { 
    case "-1" : return "<a href='javascript:void(0);'><img src='"+baseUrl+"/assets/images/icons/pending.png'></a>"; break; 
    case "0" : return "<a href='javascript:void(0);'><img src='"+baseUrl+"/assets/images/icons/cancel.png'></a>"; break; 
    case "1" : return "<a href='javascript:void(0);'><img src='"+baseUrl+"/assets/images/icons/create.png'></a>"; break; 
    case "2" : return "<a href='javascript:void(0);'><img src='"+baseUrl+"/assets/images/icons/verified.png'></a>"; break; 
    default : return "N/A"; 
    } 
    } 
    }
```

Controller code

```
$n=1;
      foreach($order_list as $r) {

           $data[] = array(
                "Sr_No" => $n,
                "cust_id" =>base64_encode($this->encryption->encrypt($r->cust_id)),//encrpt the id 
                "Name"=>$r->c_firstname."".$r->c_lastname,
                "Products"=> $r->o_product_brandname,
                "Mobile"=>$r->mobile,
                "Email"=>$r->email,
                "orderStatus"=>$r->o_order_status,
                "o_order_status"=>$r->o_order_status
           );
           $n++;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the html before the switch statement. This should work for you.

```
{ "data": null, 
  "render": function (data, type, full, meta) 
  { 
    var btnView = "<a href='"+baseUrl+"/Controller_control/get_customer?key="+full["cust_id"]+"'><img src='"+baseUrl+"/assets/images/icons/view.png'></a> |"; 
    switch(full["o_order_status"]) 
    { 
        case "-1" : return btnView + "<a href='javascript:void(0);'><img src='"+baseUrl+"/assets/images/icons/pending.png'></a>"; break; 
        case "0" : return  btnView + "<a href='javascript:void(0);'><img src='"+baseUrl+"/assets/images/icons/cancel.png'></a>"; break; 
        case "1" : return  btnView + "<a href='javascript:void(0);'><img src='"+baseUrl+"/assets/images/icons/create.png'></a>"; break; 
        case "2" : return  btnView + "<a href='javascript:void(0);'><img src='"+baseUrl+"/assets/images/icons/verified.png'></a>"; break; 
        default : return btnView + "N/A"; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, There was some power issue at my home. Give me some time to check your answer.

Comment: There is some  SyntaxError: missing name after . operator

Comment: I tried your code but my view button is displaying but a switch case is not working. I am getting only N/A. I am getting te value -1,1,0 but still showing only N/A

Comment: @user9437856 without knowing what is in `full["o_order_status"] ` I can't help you.

Comment: I updated the code. I am getting the value of  "o_order_status" but in switch not working. I am getting the only N/A

Comment: Share the value here. I can't help you if I don't know what it has. `console.log(full["o_order_status"] );` and share the output from the log here.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this to add more than one buttons. you can also add conditions to show the requried buttons.

```
 $n=1;

      foreach($order_list as $r) {
         $action = "<button>view</button>"
         $action .= "<button>Pending</button>";
           $data[] = array(
                "Sr_No" => $n,
                "cust_id" =>base64_encode($this->encryption->encrypt($r->cust_id)),//encrpt the id 
                "Name"=>$r->c_firstname."".$r->c_lastname,
                "Products"=> $r->o_product_brandname,
                "Mobile"=>$r->mobile,
                "Email"=>$r->email,
                "orderStatus"=>$action
           );
           $n++;
      }
```

Comment: My answer is right why did you click arrow down on vote. if i am wrong then correct me.